# Complex Analysis vectors perpendicular and have same magnitude..

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$= $u(x,y)$ + $iv(x,y)$ is differentiable at $z_0$=$x_0$ + $iy_0$, with $f'(z_0)\neq$ 0. Show that the vectors $\nabla u(x_0,y_0)$ and $\nabla v(x_0,y_0)$ are perpendicular and have the same magnitude. Show that the same is true for $g(z)$ = $\bar{z}$ at every point; hence the converse doesn't hold.

I'm unsure if I am thinking about this problem correctly..could one help?

Comment: do you know about cauchy riemann?

Answer (score 0):

We have $\nabla u(x_0,y_0)=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0),\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\right)$ and $\nabla v(x_0,y_0)=\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0),\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\right)$. But then, by the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\nabla v(x_0,y_0)=\left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0),\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\right)$. So, if $\nabla u(x_0,y_0)=(a,b)$, then $\nabla v(x_0,y_0)=(-b,a)$. The vectors $(a,b)$ and $(-b,a)$ are orthogonal and have the same magnitude.

If $g(z)=\overline z$, then $g(x+yi)=x-yi$. If $u(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=-y$, then $g(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$. But then $\nabla u(x_0,y_0)=(1,0)$ and $\nabla v(x_0,y_0)=(0,-1)$. The vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$ are orthogonal and have the same magnitude.